# Replace each alphabetic character in passCode with '&'

Tags: c++

new to programming here. I'm confused as to how I'm supposed to use "isalpha" to figure this out. I have no clue how to start it.

A 2-character string, passCode, is read from input. Replace each alphabetic character in passCode with '&'. Otherwise, passCode is not changed.

Ex: If the input is c4, then the output is:

&4

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   string passCode;

   getline(cin, passCode);
   
      
   cout << passCode << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: *I have no clue how to start it.* -- No clue whatsoever?  Start with a `for` loop that inspects each character.

Comment: I haven't learned how to do for loops yet, I'm barely on if statements. Yes, as in no clue whatsoever. It's saying to use "isalpha", but the the information given about this in my online book doesn't mention anything about how to replace alphabet with special characters...

Comment: Try `std::transform(passCode.begin(), passCode.end(), passCode.begin(), [](char c) { return std::isalpha(c) ? '&' : c; });` ... although, if this is homework, your teacher may ask you to explain how it works.

Comment: What about using an "if" statement with isalpha? It's supposed to just be a simple statement... But It's so confusing because none of this is mentioned in the material.

Comment: OK, more simply: `if (isalpha(passCode[0])) passCode[0] = '&';`. Same for `passCode[1]`.

Comment: `#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   string passCode;

   getline(cin, passCode);
   
   if (isalpha(passCode[0])) {
    passCode[0] = '&';
   }
   
   else if (isalpha(passCode[1])) {
   passCode[1] = '&';
   }
   
   else
   
      
   cout << passCode << endl;

   return 0;
`

@AdrianMole I tried that but it didn't work. I also tried doing cout << passCode[0] = '&'; << endl;

Comment: @AdrianMole And you think that mess of a std function call is how an entry level student will learn best... They only need to know how to read template functions to read the function signature and know what iterators are.

Comment: @Flin Drop the two `else`. The two `if` tests are independent, and you want the `cout` line regardless of whether either character has been changed.

Comment: @Flin-PaoloRoxasCabagnot -- [std::isalpha](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha).  The documentation for `std::isalpha` plus any of the other C++ standard functions are there.  There is no need to look through your textbook (however it should be there) -- the online documentation is readily available.

Comment: @AdrianMole Geez, thanks for that. Dropping the `else` helped and I got it correct...

 
   `if ( isalpha(passCode.at(0)) ) {
      passCode.at(0) = '&';
   }
   
   if ( isalpha(passCode.at(1)) ) {
      passCode.at(1) = '&';
   }`

Answer (score 0):

In many many programming languages, so called ***loop***s are used to execute or repeat blocks of code.

Or do ***iterate*** over "something". Therefore loops are also called ***Iteration statements***

Also C++ has *loops* or *iteration statements*. The basic loop constructs are

- [for loops](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for),
- [while loops](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/while),
- [do-while loops](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/do)
- [Range-based for loops](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)

Please click on the links and read the descriptions in the C++ reference. You can use any of them to solve your problem.

---

Additionally, you need to know that a `string` is a ***container***. *Container* means that a varibale of such a type ***contains*** other elements from nearly any type.

A `string` for example, contains characters.

Example: If you have a string equivalent to "Hello", then it contains the characters 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'.

Another nice property of some containers is, that they have an *index* operator or better said, a ***subscript*** operator `[]`. So, if you want to access a charcter in your string, you may simply use your variable name with an index specified in the subscript operator.

**Very important**:  Indices in C++ start with 0. So the first character in a `string` is at index 0. Example:

```
std::string test = "Hello";
std::cout << test[0];
```

will print `H`

With all the above gained know how, we can now solve your problem easily. We will iterate over all characters in your string, and then check, if a character is an alphabetic charcter. In that case, we will replace it.

One of many many possible implementations:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string passCode;

    getline(cin, passCode);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < passCode.length(); ++i) {

        if (isalpha(passCode[i])) {
            passCode[i] = '&';
        }
    }

    cout << passCode << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking for when using isalpha.

Looking at the 2 character input for passCode, check each place (0 and 1) if it is a an alpha and change it to &.

```
    if (isalpha(passCode.at(0)) {
        passCode.at(0) = '&';
    }
    if (isalpha(passCode.(1)) {
        passCode.at(1) = '&';
    }
```